# In Solidity can I get data of other block other than the current one?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I hope to have something like `Block(5).hashdata`. There is something like that in Solidity to get the hash data of another block?

Answer (score 0):

Smart contracts have only access to the current EVM state. They cannot access the historical state. Thus, you cannot access the historical state in Solidity smart contracts.

This is because Ethereum nodes do not keep, or keep only limited historical state, stored on the disk unless you run specifical archive node.